# How can I quickly detect local service absent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a local application that contains a web server for exchanging JSON with a web application. The Web application itself is served from the web, meaning that browsers see them as cross-origin.

When the application is running, it provides correct cross-origin headers to allow the interchange. However, what I want is the option to quickly detect if the application is running or not.

The current method is to use AJAX to a "heartbeat" URL on the localhost service:

```
pg.init.getHeartbeat = function(port) {

    var url = pg.utils.baseUrl('heartbeat', port); // returns a localhost URL
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
        // Hooray! Application is there. Do 'hooray' stuff
      },
      error: function(data) {
        // Whoah the bus. Application not there. Do 'no application' stuff.
      }
    });
};
```

Works great in Webkit. Webkit tries to get a heartbeat, quickly fails, and does failure stuff very quickly.

Problem is in Firefox. Firefox tries to get a heartbeat, and takes between 4 and 10 seconds to fail. It might not seem like much, but 4 seconds before the UI moves the user to the next step is making the app feel very slow and unresponsive.

Any other ideas out there? As far as I can tell, changing an iFrame's src attribute and capturing a failure isn't working, either. It's not triggering the error event. And even when I can get an error to trigger from sample code, it's still taking 4 seconds, so there is no net improvement.

The web server side of things should not have any server-side scripting languages (PHP, etc.); I need the JavaScript to be able to take care of it independently.

Comment: you can set a timer to to run the "error" code, and clear the timeout in success and error. since it's local, it should be fast, no need to wait 4 seconds...

Comment: `$.ajax` has a timeout option, see docs

Comment: @dandavis, just to clarify: I put the error in the setTimeout, which "breaks" (intentionally in this case) the blocking nature of the callback. The code assumes there is an error after X seconds rather than waiting for the error callback. Then clear on success and error to avoid firing a second time. That sound about right?

Comment: yeah, that sounds like it should work fine. i'd also look into the native timeout provided by jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a timeout if the navigator is Firefox:

```
var timeoutcall = 0;
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1)
{
     timeoutcall = 100;
}
     $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'GET',
          timeout: timeoutcall ,
          async: true,
          success: function(data) {
            // Hooray! Application is there. Do 'hooray' stuff
          },
          error: function(data) {
            // Whoah the bus. Application not there. Do 'no application' stuff.
          }
        });
```

If the timeout is 0 then there is no timeout. So, if i am in firefox i set timeout to 100ms, and if im not in firefox set to unlimited.

Comment: The idea is sound. 100ms turned out to be too short, but I can definitely tune the timeout to something less than 4-9 seconds and still not be overly concerned about false negatives.

Comment: Yes, probably is too short. But the example is illustrative. Sorry my bad english. Hope it helps.

Comment: It definitely helps, Juan! Thanks for taking time to answer.